# How to install and run xlsx2csv on Fedora 19?

Tags: fedora, csv

I was not able to run `xlsx2csv` at the command line on Fedora 19

```
[ec2-user@localhost Downloads]$ xlsx2csv
bash: xlsx2csv: command not found...
```

So I looked to install the corresponding RPM package which it turns out is already installed.

```
[ec2-user@localhost Downloads]$ sudo rpm -U xls2csv-1.06-14.fc19.noarch.rpm 
warning: xls2csv-1.06-14.fc19.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID ba094068: NOKEY
package xls2csv-1.06-14.fc19.noarch is already installed
```

Trying the command to yum install I get the message that no package is available

```
[ec2-user@localhost Downloads]$ sudo yum install xlsx2csv
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No package xlsx2csv available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

So I wonder what the issue is?

Is the package installed but just not available from the command line?

Any thoughts on a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Part of the problem appears to be that you are shown package `xls2csv` but you're trying to install package `xlsx2csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per information](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/27722262/dir/fedora_19/com/xls2csv-1.06-14.fc19.noarch.rpm.html) on rpm.pbone.net `xls2csv-1.06-14.fc19.noarch.rpm` package provides:

> Content of RPM :
> /usr/bin/convertxls2csv
> /usr/share/man/man1/convertxls2csv.1.gz

So you can use `convertxls2csv` instead of `xlsx2csv` command from this package. I think it works same as you wanted.
For more information see man page: `man convertxls2csv`.

Comment: @conteh : If you find my answer helpful and resolved your issue, Please mark the answer accepted. So that, it will come at top of other answers and will helpful to others who refer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python package manager PIP to install it.

```
sudo pip install xlsx2csv
```